# Send sms to delete user from database Kannel

Tags: php, mysql, sms, kannel

I need to send an sms to my application and based on the text, do an action. 
Now I want to delete a user when he/she sends an sms with the keyword UNSUBSCRIBE. 
I want to capture the number of the sender and the text to my phpfile which will do the delete action.

here is my sms-service configuration

```
group = sms-service
keyword = 
catch-all = true
post-url = "http://localhost/Maisha/Functions/receivesms.php?phone=%p&text=%S"
```

How do I get my values to my php file (receivesms.php) then delete the appropriate user based on their number? 
All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not delete the user from your database, you might flag them as unsubscribed as they could have more than one subscription if you follow the [Short](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code)/[Long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_number) Code subscription model. Also send the keyword 'UNSUBSCRIBE' should be 'STOP' or 'STOP ALL' (if more than one subscription). Note the keyword 'STOP' is a carrier mandate for all subscription.

As for parsing out the incoming sms, what method are you using to send with Kannel? GSM Modem? If this is a business application I would suggest going with a SMS Aggregator like [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com) or [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).

Comment: Using a GSM modem. I can send sms from my application to phone but I now want to send from phone to application. I will change it from deleting a user to user account inactive.

Comment: @Max Could you provide the type, model of the GSM Modem? and the OS you're using?

Comment: Actually I can send my sms to kannel and it gets processed. but I get a internal server error 500 in my logs. Any ideas why?